# Get the list of overlapping fixtures

Tags: c#, box2d, farseer

I have a small 2D platform game, and I want to keep track of whether the player is touching the ground (Which made of some bodies and fixtures). I figured it'll be possible to check the list of fixtures overlapping the player fixture, but is there any other, more efficient, way? If there isn't, how can I get that list?

Comment: You can use the BeginContact/EndContact notifications of the contact listener to keep track of a list of fixtures that the player is currently touching. This might help: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability

Comment: @iforce2d Thanks, that tutorial was great! I also read some other tutorials from that site (Yours, maybe?). The "One-way walls" section prevented me from asking another question :)

Comment: Note that fixtures do not actually *overlap* other fixtures in normal operation.

Answer (score 0):

could you use a hittest method? like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest.aspx) or by using AABBQuery/ HitTest (polygon/quad)

Comment: -1 This answer has nothing to do with Farseer Physics Engine.